# Is there a less verbose way to unwrap a type with only a single tag?

Tags: pattern-matching, elm, algebraic-data-types

Is there a less verbose way to unwrap a type with only a single tag, e.g. currently I do `case myObject of TheTag arg -> foo` but I'm thinking that the compiler should be smart enough to know that there's only one possibility, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in compiler shortcut that takes away the need to "unwrap" a payload from a single-constructor type. You can always define a getter function for that purpose to avoid case statements:

```
getTagArg (TheTag arg) = arg
```

And then when you need to use it in code, you would just call `getTagArg myObject` instead of the case statement.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler *is* smart enough to know that there is only one possibility, but still has to distinguish between wrapped and unwrapped values since, at the very least, they're different types.

Single tag custom types can be unwrapped, or more accurately deconstructed, anywhere a pattern can be used, just like when you deconstruct records or tuples.

You can deconstruct it in a `case` expression, as you've shown, and as a function argument

```
myFunction (TheTag arg) = ...
```

but also in a let binding

```
let TheTag arg = myObject in ...
```

If you try to do this with a custom type that has multiple tags, the compiler will tell you that "this pattern does not cover all possible values". But it works fine if the type only has one tag, since that *does* cover all possible values and the compiler *is* smart enough to recognize that.